# RTL'ing PHP hrm system - menu not working

Tags: php, jquery, css

I purchased Advanced HRM system from CodeCanyon and rtl'd it using [that CSS](http://light-era.com/hrm/assets/css/style-custom.css).
Now the [system menu](http://light-era.com/hrm/) (username: admin, password: admin.password) is not switching off, and by that not responsive as well. Support through CodeCanyon is not relevant, since they doesn't support RTL.
How can I fix it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "not switching off"? And how is this related to PHP?

Comment: In the original demo: http://preview.codecanyon.net/item/advanced-hrm/full_screen_preview/17767006?_ga=1.155233724.620821883.1475602443 we can see that the menu is folding to icons only, so it's become responsive

Comment: Oh, so you're asking us to debug a bought theme by right clicking, view source and read the code? Quite hard for us to know what's wrong since we have no idea how they built it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `style-custom.css` is a bit wrong.

The menu works in a way that it moves the menu "off screen" using a minus value as margin. When you added your own CSS, you did set the margin to 0 instead of a negative value.

Here are some changes to make it be "hidden" and to scroll out on mouse over: (which worked when I tested in the browser):

```
/* Change this one */
.left-nav-bar {
    right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: -190px; /* This hides it by pulling it off screen */
}

/* Add this one */
.left-nav-bar:hover {
    margin-right: 0; /* This positions it on the screen again */
}
```

If you want to adjust how much that is visible when it's "hidden", just adjust the value `-190px`.